# Delete fails to remove a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I do have the contents of html tables stored in a database and I use jQuery to extract the data from it and place it in another table by creating JSON objects from these tables.

I get the stored table and append it to the DOM as follow:

```
$('#divfortable).append(storedtable);
```

The next step is to create my object :

```
var tableObject = $('# divfortable tbody tr').map(function(i) { 
    var row = {}; 
    $(this).find('td').each(function(i) { 
        var rowName = columns[i]; 
        row[rowName] = $(this).text().trim(); 
    }); 
    return row; 
}).get();
```

where I have an existing array with the relevant column names.

The next step is to upload these details to the server:

```
data = { id: id, tableObject: tableObject };  
$.ajax({                    
dataType: 'json', 
url:'my_url', 
data: $.param(data),
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { },    
    success: function(data) { }
});
```

It works fine and I am very happy with the results but my problem is when repeating the process on another table. I want to get a new table and extract its contents in a similar fashion but I cannot get rid of the previous result. The result contains the newly loaded table plus that of the previous table and if I repeat it once again, it contains the result of all 3 tables!

It is obvious to me that I must empty all objects and DOM elements from the previous extraction but I tried different ways, to no avail. I gathered from searching the internet and this forum that you can use delete or empty to destroy the tableObject so that you can create a brand new one, but it does not do the job.

I tried the following:

```
delete tableObject;
```

and

```
$('#divfortable).remove(storedtable);
```

in the success function, together and separately

I also used

```
$('#divfortable).remove(storedtable);
```

after I created my data object

```
data = { id: id, tableObject: tableObject };
```

but in this case the script does not progress to the ajax call, but by displaying `$('#divfortable)` it displayed both tables!

How can I get rid of the previous result?

Comment: there's no such thing as a "JSON object".  JSON is a seralisation format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply clear the current `#divfortable` before the second operation:

```
$('#divfortable').empty();
```